# Need help keeping text on 3 lines regardless of length

Tags: javascript, jquery, line-breaks, lines

I need to find a way to keep text on 3 lines regardless of its length using jQuery. (or javascript I guess)

So this text:

```
First Project Name Combined with First Location
```

Has breaks inserted to make it look like this:

```
First Project Name
Combined with
First Location
```

While this text:

```
Second Project Name Combined with Second Location And Text To Make This Text Area Even More Incredibly Extra Long
```

Has breaks inserted to make it look like this:

```
Third Project Name Combined with Third
Location And Text To Make This Text Area
Even More Incredibly Extra Extra Long
```

I assume the code will involve counting the number of characters or spaces, dividing by 3, and then inserting breaks after so many spaces relative to the divided length. Not really sure how to write this in code though.

I have [a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Honsou/C3ehM/) set up with the actual code I'm working with. The code needs to work well with that first bit of code. (which was already graciously solved by an awesome stackoverflow user)

Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to share **your** idea of how you would approach the problem?!

Comment: Why do you need to use javascript to do what you're doing? Setting the spans that you had in your original question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11742539/trying-to-combine-two-spans-together-with-jquery-need-help-looping-iterating ) to display:block will have the same effect without scripting, but now that they're removed you've got no way to naturally differentiate between one line and another. More details about what exactly you need to achieve might help you get an answer that solves the whole problem.

Comment: hollsk is correct that using existing markup would be better, but I think it's probably better to switch the `<span>` to `<div>` rather than give `<span>` the `display: block;` styling.

Comment: Well, the two spans need to be merged together because the whole thing needs to get sized dynamically. If the first span is 1 word long, and the second is 15, the words from the second span will need to go up to the first to look right.

I can't just set them at display:block and size them, because I need the widths to be set dynamically based on how long the text is, while keeping it all on 3 lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var text = 'Text to split in lines',
    lines = [],
    chunks, i;

text = text.split(' ');
chunks = Math.ceil(text.length / 3);

for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    lines.push( text.slice(i * chunks , chunks * i + chunks ).join(' ') );
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sCRvm/

---

And here you have it [in plugin format](http://jsfiddle.net/BguKx/):

```
(function($) {
    $.fn.splitToLines = function(numberOfLines) {
        return this.each(function() {

            var $this = $(this),
                lines = [],
                text, chunks, i;

            text = $this.text().split(' ');

            chunks = Math.ceil(text.length / numberOfLines);

            for ( i = 0; i < numberOfLines; i++) {
                lines.push( text.slice(i * chunks , chunks * i + chunks ).join(' ') );
            }

            $this.html( lines.join('<br />') );

        });
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Once you include this script, you could just call it like so:

```
$('div').splitToLines(3);
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BguKx/1/

Answer (score 0):

Note: it's possible that there is a better approach to this than the one you've suggested; if there is, I don't know it, but I'm posting this as a way to achieve your suggested approach, not necessarily as the best way to solve the problem.

Assumes that the string is stored in `str`.

```
var len = str.length; // total length of the string
var breakpoint = len/3; // caching a third of it
var bp1 = -1; // location of the first <br>
var bp2 = -1; // location of the second <br>
for ( var i = 0; i < len; ++i ) // going through the entire string
{
    if ( str[i] == ' ' ) // might be a good idea to check for any whitespace character
    {
        if ( bp1 < 0 || Math.abs(breakpoint - i) < Math.abs(breakpoint - bp1) )
        { // either the first time through, or a better location for the first <br> than the previous best
            bp1 = i;
        }
        else if ( bp2 < 0 || Math.abs((bp1+breakpoint) - i) < Math.abs((bp1+breakpoint) - bp2) )
        { // either the first time after getting the first <br>, or a better location for the second <br>
            bp2 = i;
        }
    }
}
if ( bp1 > 0 && bp2 > 0 ) // found places
{
    str = str.substring(0, bp1) + '<br>' + str.substring(bp1+1, bp2) + '<br>' + str.substring(bp2+1);
}
else
{
    // didn't work; put some error checking code here?
}
```